# What does i386 mean on macOS Mojave?

Tags: osx, hardware, macintosh

I'm on a second-hand MacBook Pro from late 2013 (Mojave 10.14.3) and when I type `arch` on the Terminal, I get back `i386`. Shouldn't it be a `x86_64`? Did the seller misrepresent the item? Please see the screenshot below of *'About this Mac'*.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12763379/4500798), `arch` distinguishes between PowerPC (`ppc`) and Intel (`i386`), not between 32- and 64-bit kernels on x86. So in this context, `i386` means an x86 CPU.

Check the output of `uname -m` to find out your machine type. (On Linux, `arch` is the equivalent of `uname -m`.)

See also [this Ask Different Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/140651/203966).

Comment: yep! I did `uname -m` and it gave me `x86_64`. So I guess it's a 64 bit CPU architecture. I tried `arch` just to try out a cmd that I had bumped into while studying for a Linux certification.

Answer (score 16):

On a macOS system, as on other BSD systems, you should use the `machine` utility:

```
$ arch
i386
$ machine
x86_64h
```

The `i386` is misleading if you're used to the `arch` utility on other systems.  On macOS Mojave, `i386` means it's capable of running 32-bit software compiled for the Intel family of processors.  Note that the `arch` utility on macOS is used for quite different things compared to on e.g. Linux (see its manual).

You may also use `uname -m` as on Linux:

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

Comment: Not to make a mountain of a molehill, but AFAIK, there's no documentation from Apple to indicate that `i386` designation implies it's capable of running 32-bit software... `man arch` certainly doesn't suggest that. IMHO, Apple's just dropped the ball, and allowed things to get a bit messy - perhaps in the name of backward compatibility?

Answer (score 3):

I feel that using the "traditional" utilities (e.g. `arch`, `uname`, `sw_vers`) to discover your Mac's hardware or software may not be very reliable. It's certainly inconsistent! Even the system manuals are rife with inconsistencies.

This is not to say that you can't get useful information from these utilities, it's only to say that unless you know what you're looking for, you may get results that are *different* from what you get on other systems.

For example:

```
$ arch
i386
```

No! (Unless you're using a really old computer.)

Another example is the OS version. `man sw_vers` and `man uname` both claim to report "OS Version":

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.4
BuildVersion:   18E226

$ uname -v
Darwin Kernel Version 18.5.0 ....  # output snipped
```

Which is all well and good - we're aware that kernel and distro release version numbering is different, but the system manuals for both of these commands say you get `OS Version`. Understanding the [genesis of the current `macos`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29) explains some of this, but it doesn't explain why the system manuals are inconsistent.

And so, to the OP's question regarding how to get clear and reliable information on a system, I feel the answer should be to use `system_profiler` for both hardware and software:

```
$ system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro13,3
      Processor Name: Intel Core i7
      Processor Speed: 2.9 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 4
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 8 MB
      Memory: 16 GB
      Boot ROM Version: 254.0.0.0.0
      SMC Version (system): 2.38f7
      Serial Number (system): C02*********
      Hardware UUID: ********-****-****-****-************

$ system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 10.14.4 (18E226)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 18.5.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: MacBook No 2
      User Name: Seamus (seamus)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      System Integrity Protection: Enabled
      Time since boot: 13:13
```

Also, the system manual for `system_profiler` seems to be maintained to a more current state.

And finally, as to the **Headline Question**: *"What does [the output of `arch`] i386 mean on macOS Mojave?"*. ***Answer:*** Unfortunately, it *means* that Apple has not maintained their documentation and/or apps properly.